# Cannot read property 'routeName' of undefined - react navigation drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

[image: test]
I keep getting this error every time i pass values to drawer config, but when i use it without passing any config it works fine.

I get error using this:

```
const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
 AboutUs: { screen: AboutUsScreen },
 Options: { screen: OptionsScreen },
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
  }, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
   drawerPosition: 'right',
  });
```

No error using this:

```
   const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
   AboutUs: { screen: AboutUsScreen },
   Options: { screen: OptionsScreen },
   Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
   });
```

I spent hours trying to figure it out but no luck.

Full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import {
Platform,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View
} from 'react-native';

import { Card, ListItem, Button, Icon } from 'react-native-elements'
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import HomeScreen from './Home'
import OptionsScreen from './Options'
import AboutUsScreen from './AboutUs'


const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
AboutUs: { screen: AboutUsScreen },
Options: { screen: OptionsScreen },
Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
}, {
initialRouteName: 'Home',
drawerPosition: 'right',
});


export default Drawer ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added:

```
 drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
 drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
 drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
```

to  drawer config and it's working now :)